# how to keep checkbox checked during pagination in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, pagination

Right now i am working on a system like exam system and in that system one student can give the exam for multiple subjects. So i make a pagination for each subjects. **But my questions is, is that possible to keep checkbox checked during pagination.** Like here is my quiz form and **I want to get a technique so that if i paginate to the next page and again if i redirect back to the previous page then all the checkbox is remain checked that i already checked before**
 [image]

Please help me to get this. It will be really helpful for me

Comment: do you have any idea with these???it can be helpful

Comment: Use session to store key value pair of what is checked

Comment: can you show an example.....please

Comment: That is very well documented https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session

Answer (score 1):

You need to send ajax request to server on each click on checkbox. On server you need to store question answer in DB or session. Then if you render previous page you need to check if question option checked (record exists in DB or session).

See:

- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#if-statements
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#storing-data